PoE+ output voltage
I would like to measure the output voltage from a PoE+ injector.
This is the schematic provided for the PoE+ injector that I am testing.

Can someone help me out with that?
Here is a link to the document. http://tag-tech.cn/upfile/GS2402SIP.pdf

That is only the drawing of the magnetics.  If you google POE pinout you'll find the pins to measure.

understood, thanks
